# network manager dbus interface calls for wireless doesnt work on raspbian

Tags: pi-3, wifi, access-point, networkmanager, dbus

I have the following code to retrieve access points information using NetworkManager dbus api:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    QDBusInterface dbus_iface("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager",                     
                              "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2",     // path (might be different in other systems)
                              "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless",     
                              bus);


    QDBusMessage query = dbus_iface.call("GetAllAccessPoints");

    qDebug() << query;

    if(query.type() == QDBusMessage::ReplyMessage) {

        QDBusArgument arg = query.arguments().at(0).value<QDBusArgument>();
        arg.beginArray();
        while(!arg.atEnd()) {
            QString element = qdbus_cast<QString>(arg);
            netList->append(element);
            showAccessPointProperties(element);
        }
        arg.endArray();
    } else {
        qDebug() << " dbus error: " << query.errorName();
    }
```

This code works on desktop linux (ubuntu 18.04).

But in raspbian (buster, raspberry pi 3 B/B+) this code doesn't work! The problem is that this call :

```
dbus_iface.call("GetAllAccessPoints");
```

returns empty reply.

Is it anything different on how to use NM dbus interface in raspbian and ubuntu?

Comment: `"/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2",` : Is that the correct path to the wireless device. That might be correct on your PC (Ubuntu?)  but is it the right path on the raspi too? If e.g you ask your network card for all access points, it gives you all it can find: 0. I have not much knowledge on the DBus so I can not tell you how to find the correct device number. For me the comment `// path (might be different in other systems)`  would be sufficient to investigate in that direction.

Comment: Have you added and configured NM on Raspbian, it's not used by default?

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer in my the it is devices/3, I'm aware of the difference of wireless path in different systems as mentioned in the comment. this path is for my PC.
My question is that why GetAllAccessPoints returns nothing in Pi?

Comment: @Dougie Yes, I've installed NM myself. Do you aware of any configuration that might be related to this issue?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the words "in my the it is devices/3". And I'm also confused: is the code above the code running on the pi or on the PC. If you know that the wireless device is "devices/3", why do you target the request to another device. Or do you say that you used the 3 in the Program for the pi? I understand your question, but I might not understand what you've done so far. I'm not a native English speaker (I'm even not very skilled in), so it is very hard for me to interpret uncompleted sentences or slang.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer: In my pi it is devices/3, Actually I've solved the issue by removing openresolve and dhcpcd5 from pi. It seems that services in these packages prevent NM to access wireless devices.

Comment: @payman In future you are better off asking these kinds of questions on our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)  -- Raspbian is not particularly unusual in this regard, although it uses dhcpcd by default (which I do not think current stock Debian does) -- or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), since it is programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that other network managing packages prevent Network Manager to access wireless.

For me the issue resolved by removing *dhcpcd5* and *openresolve* packages :

> sudo apt-get remove --purge dhcpcd5 openresolve

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.